# weird gui and blue desktop background

Tags: graphics

I have searched all over the internet for a solution to this problem, but all the solutions I've found have not worked.

I installed ubuntu onto my laptop. Once it installed everything was working fine, I installed plex media server from the application downloader, and went to download something it else, and it said I didn't have permissions. Weird, but I figured it was something I had done wrong. So I figured I would mess with that later. I then noticed I could not open up anything at all. So I did the logical thing, I restarted my laptop.

This is when my problem started. My laptop now boots into a desktop with blue wallpaper, no icons and nothing on my favorites bar, and nothing I do working. I can still see text and stuff on the screen but nothing is actually working.

I would include what I have tried, but I am completely new to ubuntu and i have just been trying whatever I can find to get it working, and haven't really kept note.

computer specs are 4gb ram pretty sure ddr3, intel pentium processor, its a laptop I have had laying around for a bit. Hp notebook 15 to be exact.

and ubuntu version Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS[image]

Comment: Let's starts with the basics. Please EDIT your question and post hardware specifications and Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: A screenshot or picture might help as well 

Comment: Before you sign in, select the gear icon and then select the Gnome desktop or Ubuntu desktop. Have you tried this?

Comment: I am not able to add a picture to the post, due to needing reputation, and I have added the specs to the post.

Comment: @mchid I am not given the option to log in, as it goes straight to the desktop when booting. if I force the log in screen to appear it also has a messed up gui and there is no gear icon, just the name and password areas.

Comment: Now I am able to add photos, accidentally added the same photo twice.

Comment: Try logging out (not shutting down but logging out) of that desktop and then see if you  can get options from that sign in screen. It might not be a gear icon, idk because I use lightdm. Sometimes the option is in a dropdown menu that is accessible from the top panel.

Comment: @mchid i clicked around the log in screen and found some drop downs, but nothing to do with  selecting a desktop

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing your icons and maybe you switched themes after installing the plex server.

**First**, install `gnome-tweaks` by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

**Next**, open the Gnome Tweaks application or run the command: `gnome-tweaks`

**Then**, under "appearance" try selecting some of the different themes for icons and others. I believe the default theme for Gnome Shell is Adwaita.

**Also**, it might be a good idea to make sure that the default Ubuntu desktop is still installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
```

Comment: when i type sudo apt gnome-tweaks it says invalid operation gnome-tweaks. also I believe reinstalling ubuntu desktops was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: i would also like to add, that nothing  opens up if I try to load it. Not even settings. the only thing i can get to open is terminal.

Comment: @CaseyJones There was a typo which has been fixed.

Comment: @CaseyJones Also, if you need to open Gnome Tweaks from the command line, you can use the command: `gnome-tweaks`